# why does font-family fallback to user-agent when css variable is defined but font is not available

Tags: css, font-family, css-variables

The situation is when using css variables with font-family, the defined default font-family is not the fallback font-family.

We have a css variable defined for --myFontFamily.

When the font-family defined by the css variable --myFontFamily is not available on the site, the user-agent font-family is utilized.

The expectation is that our default font-family will be the fallback when the  css variable font-family is not available.  For clarity --myFontFamily is defined.  The value is a custom font that does not exist on the site.

I have reviewed [webstyle guide](https://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/8-typography/4-web-typefaces.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20specify%20a%20font,pages%20in%20their%20favorite%20font.)

I reviewed [css vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

we utilize the shadowDOM for our content so we utilize the sudo class for :host {}  to ensure proper style cascading for elements inside the shadowDOM.

css variable will be injected into the head of the html within a style tag

elements that do not define font-family will inherit the font-family defined within :host {}

```
<style type="text/css" class="custom-site-style" id="custom-site-styles">
    :root {
      --myFontFamily: CustomFontButNotOnTheSitePage;
    }
  </style>


<div>
  <!-- there would be a shadow-root here -->
  <style>
    :host {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
    }

    .my-content {
      font-family: var(--myFontFamily);
    }
  </style>

  <div> Font Family is Arial as expected </div>
  <div class="my-content">  User Agent font-family is used.  Expectation is for font family to default to Arial because the css variable is defined but the font does not exist on the site page.  We have a defined font-family that is inherited by other elements.
  </div>
</div>
```

I have experimented and found that this will work and fallback to the default font-family as expected.  However this doesn't explain why the user-agent is the fallback in the above example.

```
<div>
  <style>
    :host {
      --defaultFontFamily: Arial, Helvetica;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;

    }

    .my-content {
      font-family: var(--myFontFamily), var(--defaultFontFamily);
    }
  </style>
```

As requested.  A true working example.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Times New Roman';
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css" class="custom-site-style" id="custom-site-styles">
            :root {
              --myFontFamily: CustomFontButNotOnTheSitePage;
            }
          </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="inject-here">

        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {// mimics proprietary production code
            const content = document.querySelector('.inject-here');
            if (!content.shadowRoot) {
                const shadow = content.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
                
                // demonstrates the issue observed
                // when the custom variable has defined a font-family that does not exist on the page
                // the default font-family will cascade from the page / user agent 
                // rather than from the defined styles in :host {}
                const hostStyles = `
                    :host {
                        font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
                        /*demonstrates the :host is correct*/
                        color: blue; 
                        font-weight: 500;
                    }

                    .my-content {
                        font-family: var(--myFontFamily);
                        color: black; /*demonstrates cascade works*/
                    }`;

                // // working example of explicit default font-family will be used as the fallback
                // // uncomment this to see it work properly
                // const hostStyles = `
                //     :host {
                //         --myDefaultFontFamily: Arial, Helvetica;
                //         font-family: var(--myDefaultFontFamily);
                //         /*demonstrates the :host is correct*/
                //         color: blue; 
                //         font-weight: 500;
                //     }

                //     .my-content {
                //         font-family: var(--myFontFamily), var(--myDefaultFontFamily);
                //         color: black; /*demonstrates cascade works*/
                //     }`;

                

                shadow.innerHTML = `<style>
                    ${hostStyles}
                </style>
                <div> Content font-family will be Arial or Helvetica</div>
                <div class="my-content">User Agent font-family will be used here.  Expected that the :host font-family would be used</div>`;
            }
        }());

        
        
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: we need to see the real code where :host is used. Actually we cannot verify the correct usage of host

Comment: can we make a presumption shadowDom is correct and other styles are working?  I may be able to create a script you can run locally that creates a real example.

simplified question is why does this work
.my-content {
      font-family: var(--myFontFamily), var(--defaultFontFamily);
    }

and this does not
.my-content {
      font-family: var(--myFontFamily);
    }

Comment: @TemaniAfif as requested i created a working example and copied to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS vars are irrelevant to the problem.
Replacing the var with the actual value gives the following CSS which is simpler to reason with:

```css
:host {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
.my-content {
  font-family: DefinedButNotOnTheSitePage;
}
```

`font-family: DefinedButNotOnTheSitePage;` is a syntactically valid CSS declaration, so the browser will apply it to `.my-content`, ‘replacing’ the existing font-family inherited to the element just like any other CSS property.

Only if it was an invalid declaration would the browser ignore it and have `Arial, Helvetica` inherited.

Since a font called `DefinedButNotOnTheSitePage` cannot be found, and the CSS declaration has no fallback fonts specified, the user agent's defined fallback font is used.

---

For example,

```css
:host {
  color: red;
}
.my-content {
  color: yellow;
}
```

does not make `.my-content` orange. CSS declarations are not combined together; `.my-content` will be yellow.

However,

```css
:host {
  color: red;
}
.my-content {
  color: abcdefghi;
}
```

`.my-content` will be red because `color: abcdefghi;` is invalid: there is no color `abcdefghi` at the time of reading the CSS.

For `color`, the spec says what values are possible as named colors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/named-color

If the color value is a name but is not in this list, the CSS declaration is immediately invalid and ignored.

However `font-family` does not have a fixed list of possible values in spec.

> ```
> font-family = 
>   [ <family-name> | <generic-family> ]#
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Therefore at the point of reading the CSS any string that could be a family-name is allowed.

It is only later when looking up the font given that it cannot be found. That doesn't make the CSS declaration invalid and ignored — it's ‘too late’ for that.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I'm still not certain why the default is not the : host font-family.  Are you saying that      ` font-family: DefinedButNotOnTheSitePage;`     will always default to the site styles / user agent when the font-family is invalid or non-existent?

Comment: @greg I've edited my answer to hopefully clarify why font-family works different to other named values for other properties like color where it's a fixed list in spec.

Comment: Thanks again for your responses and help.  It clarifies what's going on and the "it's too late for that"  confirms what the issue is.  Thanks you.